# How can I rejoin this server later in 7 Days to Die?

Tags: xbox-one, 7-days-to-die

I am playing on console and joined a random multiplayer server. I played for a little bit but then left to try and find a more active server. I ended getting placed into a different random server and had to start over (inventory, skills, levels, etc). Is there a way that I can rejoin a previous server ? Can I favorite a server ?

I want to make sure I can return to this server later as I don't want to lose my progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anyway at this time to achieve what you want.  I have the game on the same system, and cannot find a way to do this.  Since there is no defined server list to choose from, and the "servers" are really just other players hosting, its random every time from what I can tell.

Private games offer a solution to this, or hosting your own public game as well, though [I have run into many issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285969/connectivity-problems-with-7-days-to-die) trying to play this game online with friends due to connectivity issues.  Most of the time, when I am hosting my public game, it is rare for someone to join (not sure if its because of all the problems, or because not many play the game).

I suppose the one other work around is finding out who the host is of the game, and having them invite you back.  This is for obvious reasons, a nuisance though, since you're bound to another person being on at the same time.

Comment: Well that's disappointing :( I guess I will be hosting then! Haha

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep rejoining a server right now is figure out who is running it and send them a friends request. That way you can keep joining.